# Create both IPv4 and IPv6 SPF record

Tags: dns, ipv6, spf

Right now I have SPF IP4 and IP6 as two separate records, but IPv6 is not being recognized by Gmail. Should I merge them? It looks like this currently. How should it be configured?

```
  A   3600     0  78.46.138.249
 MX   3600    10  mx.zohomail.com
 MX   3600    20  mx2.zohomail.com
 NS   3600     0  ns1.loopia.se
 NS   3600     0  ns2.loopia.se
TXT   3600     0  "v=spf1 ip4:78.46.138.249 ~all"
TXT    300     0  "v=spf1 ip6:2a01:4f8:d16:1355::2 +all"
```

GMail:

```
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning info@dadilja.rs does not designate 2a01:4f8:d16:1355::2 as permitted sender) client-ip=2a01:4f8:d16:1355::2;
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think this is a duplicate of [Will adding a second SPF record mess up my DNS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/29777/will-adding-a-second-spf-record-mess-up-my-dns) on Server Fault.

In short: yes, you must merge them. The specs do not allow multiple SPF records.

The resultant merged record should be:

```
TXT "v=spf1 ip4:78.46.138.249 ip6:2a01:4f8:d16:1355::2 ~all"
```

Comment: Could you add an example to your post on how to merge them?

Comment: In this (simple) example the resulting record would be `TXT "v=spf1 ip4:78.46.138.249 ip6:2a01:4f8:d16:1355::2 ~all"`

Comment: Note that it seems preferred to use "-all" instead of "~all": https://serverfault.com/questions/355511/is-using-softfail-over-fail-in-the-spf-record-considered-best-practice/752911#752911

Answer (score 13):

Yes it is possible and it works, a SPF with both ip6 & Ip4 would look like:

```
"v=spf1 ip4:XX.XX.XX.XX ip6:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX ~all"
```

You can also in both cases add a CIDR (basis: /32 for ipv4 & /128 for ipv6) after each address to authorize a network range rather than a host.

Comment: why did you reserve 8 fields for ipv6?

Comment: IPv6 addresses are represented as eight groups of four hexadecimal digits with the groups being separated by colons, for example 2001:0db8:0000:0042:0000:8a2e:0370:7334